# Find the Lowest Common Multiple of three polymonials.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the L.C.M. of $13ab^2(x^3-3a^2x+2a^3),\ 65a^3b(x^2+ax-2a^2),\ 25b^3(x^2-a^2)^2$

$13ab^2(x^3-3a^2x+2a^3)\\5*13a^3b(x+2a)(x-a)\\5^2b^3(x-a)^2(x+a)^2$

Hence the L.C.M. is $5^2*13a^3b^3(x-a)^2(x+a)^2(x+2a)(x^3-3a^x+2a^3)$

But the answer is given as $325a^3b^3(x-a)^2(x+a)^2(x+2a)$

From my understanding apparently $(x^3-3a^2x+2a^3)$ can be factored. But I can't see how it's possible. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It clearly has a factor $x-a$. What is the remaining quadratic factor then?

Comment: How can you tell x-a is clearly a factor? I can't tell at all. Is there a specific method or this is just intuition? Thanks.

Comment: Plugging in $x=a$ yields $0$, so $x-a$ is a factor.

Answer (score 1):

You can factorize the first polynomial like these steps, which shows $(x-a)$ is a factor of the polynomial-

$x^3-3a^2x+2a^3 \\= (x^3-3x^2a + 3ax^2-a^3) +3x^2a +3a^3 - 6a^2x \\= (x-a)^3 + 3a(x^2-2ax+a^2) \\=(x-a)^3 + 3a(x-a)^2\\= (x-a)^2[(x-a) + 3a] \\= (x-a)^2(x+2a)$

Therefore, LCM would be $5^2.13a^3b^3(x-a)^2(x+a)^2(x+2a)$